# Why is Gayatri Devi called Chaturanana (4-headed) when She's considered to be Panchamukhi (5-faced)?

Tags: gayatri-mantra, gayatri

I'm doing Gayatri Sadhana by Om Swami and I've come across this shloka: "Om balam vidyam tu gayatrim lohitam chaturananam, raktambaradwayopetam..." and the translation says four-faced.

But Gayatri Devi is generally considered to be Five-faced (Panchamukhi). Am I missing something?